# Use 'try', 'raise', 'except' function to write a short program

Tags: python, typeerror, except, valueerror, raiserror

Consider a Circle class used to represent circle objects.  Instances of the Circle class will have an attribute called radius which indicates the size of the circle.  The constructor method (e.g. **init**) for this class will initialise this attribute as usual.

Clearly, it doesn't make sense for a Circle object to have a size less than or equal to 0.

If someone attempts to create a Circle object with a negative or zero radius, then you should raise an exception of type ValueError.  The ValueError object should be created with the following string:

Radius must not be less than or equal to 0

In addition, If someone attempts to create a Circle object with a non-integer valued radius, then you should raise an exception of type TypeError.  The ValueError object should be created with the following string:

Radius must be an integer value

Define a Circle class with a constructor method that prevents Circle object being created with an invalid radius.  The **repr** and **str** functions of this class should return the following string:

Circle(x)

where x is the radius of the circle.

For example:

```
def main():
    try:
      c = Circle(10)
    except ValueError as x:
      print("Error: " + str(x))
    else:
      print(c)
def __init__(self, x):
    try:
      if x <= 0:
        raise ValueError('Radius must not be less than or equal to 0')
      elif x != int or x != float:
        raise TypeError('Radius must be an integer value')
    except ValueError as x:
        print('Error: {0}'.format(x))
    except TypeError as x:
        print('Error: {0}'.format(x))
main()
```

The result should be:

```
Circle(10)
```

If c = Circle(-100), the result should be:

```
Error: Radius must not be less than or equal to 0
```

However, the part of "def **init**(self, x)" is incorrect.
Can somebody please help?!
Thanks!

Comment: You don't seem to have a Circle class anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a number of mistakes:

First off, you say you want a "Circle class", but you don't actually define one.
You must create a class `Circle` and move your `__init__` inside of it.

Second, this line is incorrect:

```
elif x != int or x != float:
```

I presume that your intention here was to make sure that `x` is either a float or an integer, and raise an error if it isn't. However, the way this is written, one of the two conditions will always be True: Either `x` is an integer so `x != float` is True, `x` is a float so `x != int` is True, or `x` is neither so they are both True.

Modify the elif statement like so:

```
elif not isinstance(x, (int, float)):
```

Third, you probably need to switch the order of the if and elif, otherwise passing any non-numerical value to the constructor will cause the `<=` to throw an exception.

Finally, you can turn those two `except`s into one:

```
except (ValueError, TypeError) as x:
```

So the final result will be:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, x):
        try:
            if not isinstance(x, (int, float)):
                raise TypeError('Radius must be an integer value')
            elif x <= 0:
                raise ValueError('Radius must not be less than or equal to 0')
        except (ValueError, TypeError) as x:
            print('Error: {0}'.format(x))
```

Comment: You can shorten the line `elif not (isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, float)):` to simply `elif not isinstance(x, (int, float))`. `isinstance` can accept a tuple of type arguments to test it's first argument against.

Comment: @ChristianDean Thanks for the tip kind sir. I have edited my answer.